# Is it okay to write HTML code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I wanted to create a Single page App without using front-end frameworks, since it was a small project.

So when user clicks on navigation, it fires an AJAX call and appends (HTML code with formatted data) it to HTML.

This is how it looks: https://gist.github.com/yask123/c786f49c7118e4cd91eab5c56f69257d

Is it super bad practice to do so ? Or should I use Handlebar.js just for this? (Would it be an overkill just for one thing ..? )

Live app: http://dtumart.com/

Comment: Back-end should not take any actions that involve layout, it should be done on front-end side.

Comment: This is being done on the front-end

Comment: its a little fugly, but if its maintainable, its probably ok, you could look at any one of a number of tiny size js templating frameworks if the reason for avoiding them is overkill/filesize. Really its to make your life easier to modify/maintain

Comment: @Justinas I might have misunderstood you, can you explain in a little more detail what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is okay to write code in your logic (JavaScript).

Loading an entire framework/library for a single action is usually overkill and there can be several benefits to creating your code in the logic.

The only real concern here is if your JavaScript fails, or the clients browser doesn't support, then the client won't see anything.